# WPF Bind Count of Items to TextBlock Foreground Colour

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a converter class that binds a Count of TagName to FontSize as shown below. What I am now trying to achieve is for every 3 increments of FontSize bind to a different colour. Can anyone help?

**Converter**

```
public class CountToFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        const int minFontSize = 6;
        const int maxFontSize = 38;
        const int increment = 3;
        int count = (int)value;

        if ((minFontSize + count + increment) < maxFontSize)
        {
            return minFontSize + count + increment;            
        }
        return maxFontSize;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**XAML Snippet**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TagsTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=Default}" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       FontSize="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}, Mode=Default}" 
                       Foreground="#FF0D0AF7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**New DataTemplate**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TagsTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=Default}" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       FontSize="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}, Mode=Default}" 
                       Foreground="{Binding count, Converter={StaticResource CountToBrushConverter}}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That `increment` variable is quite useless i think, you could just as well throw it out and set the `minfontsize` to 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low count = Black;
High Count = Blue;

```
public class CountToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        const int cap = 32;
        int count = (int)value;
        count -= count % 3; // Modulo division to make sure
                            // that the value only changes
                            // every 3 steps

        double res = count <= cap ? count : cap; // Check if maximum
                                                 // has been reached
        res /= cap; // Normalize value to be between 0 and 1
        Color colour = new Color();
        colour.ScA = 1; // Set the alpha to full visibility
        colour.ScB = (float)res; // Set the blue channel to our value

        return new SolidColorBrush(colour);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although that did not seem to change the colour - is it because I have 2 converters in my wndows.resources?

Comment: You need to create an instance of that converter and use it in the binding of the `Foreground` property.

Comment: I have updated my question - I think this is what u mean but still no luck.

Comment: Do you have a property called `count`? No you don't. So obviously don't bind to it (you should see errors like that in the Output window, use it!), you also need to bind to `ItemCount` as with the FontSize.

Comment: Thanks H.B. - thats works but if possible could you explain how your converter works for my understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another converter that will convert current font size to a brush. The converter might look something like this:

```
public class FontSizeToBrushConverter : IValueConverter {
    public static readonly double Increment = 3;
    public static readonly double MinFontSize = 6;
    public static readonly double MaxFontSize = 32;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value == null || value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        var fontSize = (double) value;

        double incrementsCount = MaxFontSize / Increment;

        var defaultColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        for (int incrementIndex = 0; incrementIndex < incrementsCount; incrementIndex++) {
            if (fontSize == MinFontSize + Increment * incrementIndex) {
                switch (incrementIndex) {
                    case 0:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    case 1:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    case 2:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                    default:
                        return defaultColor; // Default color
                }
            }
        }

        return defaultColor; // Default color
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You might want to move the constants defined on the top of this class somewhere to share them between your two converters.

Using this converter your XAML will look like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TagsTemplate">
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=Default}" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               FontSize="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}, Mode=Default}" 
               Foreground="{Binding FontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource FontSizeToBrushConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```